# Extract x and y values from a list

Tags: python, list

I have list like this:

```
pp=[[0,0] , [-1,5], [2,3], [1,5], [3,6], [4,5], [5,3], [8,-2], [4, -4], [2, -5]]
```

And I want to extract x and y values in separate lists like:

```
ppx= [0, -1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is the most straightforward way:

```
xs = [p[0] for p in pp]
ys = [p[1] for p in pp]
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `zip()` to separate the coordinates:

```
ppx, ppy = zip(*pp)
```

This produces tuples; these are easily enough mapped to `list` objects:

```
ppx, ppy = map(list, zip(*pp))
```

This works in both Python 2 and 3 (where the `map()` iterator is expanded for the tuple assignment).

Demo:

```
>>> pp=[[0,0] , [-1,5], [2,3], [1,5], [3,6], [4,5], [5,3], [8,-2], [4, -4], [2, -5]]
>>> ppx, ppy = zip(*pp)
>>> ppx
(0, -1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 4, 2)
>>> ppy
(0, 5, 3, 5, 6, 5, 3, -2, -4, -5)
>>> ppx, ppy = map(list, zip(*pp))
>>> ppx
[0, -1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 4, 2]
>>> ppy
[0, 5, 3, 5, 6, 5, 3, -2, -4, -5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions:

```
pp=[[0,0] , [-1,5], [2,3], [1,5], [3,6], [4,5], [5,3], [8,-2], [4, -4], [2, -5]]
ppx=[a[0] for a in pp]
ppy=[a[1] for a in pp]
```

More on list comprehensions in the Python docs: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions